# Filling in my own Web Audio Buffer is not working

Tags: html, audio, web

I'm using Web Audio for various purposes and while samples loaded via URL and oscillators are working and playing properly, building a custom source buffer is not. I have tried to load my own AudioBuffer into an AudioBufferSourceNode using the code below and through the Chrome-NetBeans debugger I can see that it's loading the buffer with data and no errors are flagged, but when start is called, no sound is ever produced. Note that I'm just filling the buffer with noise, but I plan to fill it with my own custom wave data. I realize it's likely that I'm filling the buffer with the wrong data type, but I have been unable to find any documentation or examples regarding the proper way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var frameCount = 2000;
var sampleRate = 4000;
var myBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(2, frameCount, sampleRate);

// FILL WITH WHITE NOISE
for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
    myBuffer[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
}
sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
sourceNode.buffer = myBuffer;
sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
sourceNode.start(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will synth your noise inside a callback method which is called everytime you have rendered yet another BUFF_SIZE number of samples

```
var BUFF_SIZE = 2048; // spec allows, yet do not go below 1024 
var audio_context = new AudioContext();
var gain_node = audio_context.createGain();
gain_node.connect( audio_context.destination );
var source_node = audio_context.createScriptProcessor(BUFF_SIZE, 1, 1);

source_node.onaudioprocess = (function() {

    return function(event) {

        var synth_buff = event.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // mono for now

        // FILL WITH WHITE NOISE
        for (var i = 0, buff_size = synth_buff.length; i < buff_size; i++) {
            synth_buff[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
        }
    };
}());

source_node.connect(gain_node);
```